# BigQuery joining two tables and aggregating results

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to essentially join two tables, find the common numbers between the two, figure out the call_counterparty's name and create a results table. I want it to display the call_counterparty's and not to number which is being queried, which in our case is the (from_number). For example if you call me, you would be MY in_call counterparty and I would be your out_call counterparty. If I call you, you would be my out_call counterparty and I would be your in_call counterparty. I'm not sure how to differentiate between 'call_counterparty'.

In short, who does the person being queried call or receive calls from and what is their associated name? If a name doesn't exist for them in the table to be joined, then display null. Let's assume my phone number is 2228881111... and let's assume you can even call yourself.

The two BigQuery database tables I am working with are:

bigquery.call_log_table

```
from_number,to_number
2228881111,9997772222
2228881111,8883337777
8883337777,2228881111
2228881111,1112229999
6663332222,2228881111
2228881111,2228881111
```

bigquery.contact_list_table

```
number,name
9997772222,John
8883337777,Jill
2228881111,Me
```

Here is my current code without left join or other:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN call_log.from_number = 
'2228881111' THEN 
call_log.to_number ELSE call_log.from_number END AS 
call_counterparty,
SUM(call_log.to_number = '2228881111') AS in_call,
SUM(call_log.from_number = '2228881111') AS out_call

FROM `bigquery.call_log_table` AS call_log

WHERE '2228881111' in (call_log.from_number, call_log.to_number)
GROUP BY call_counterparty
```

Current result:

```
call_counterparty,in_call,out_call
9997772222,0,1
8883337777,1,1
1112229999,0,1
6663332222,1,0
2228881111,1,1
```

The result I want:

```
call_counterparty,counterparty_name,in_call,out_call
9997772222,John,0,1
8883337777,Jill,1,1
1112229999,<null>,0,1
6663332222,<null>1,0
2228881111,Me,1,1
```

I have tried all sorts, have spent hours, have googled a ton and I simply can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a query like this:

```
WITH call_records AS (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN call_log.from_number = '2228881111' THEN call_log.to_number ELSE call_log.from_number END AS call_counterparty
    , SUM(IF(call_log.to_number = '2228881111',1,0)) AS in_call
    , SUM(IF(call_log.from_number = '2228881111',1,0)) AS out_call
  FROM `dataset.call_log_table` AS call_log
  WHERE '2228881111' in (call_log.from_number, call_log.to_number)
  GROUP BY call_counterparty
)
SELECT call_counterparty, contacts.name, in_call, out_call
FROM call_records 
LEFT JOIN `dataset.contact_list_table` as contacts
ON call_records.call_counterparty = contacts.number
GROUP BY call_counterparty, contacts.name, in_call, out_call
```

Comment: That worked @vinoaj! I did have to define contacts.name as contact_name and group by contact_name in lieu of contacts.name and worked perfectly! You're incredible and I'm so thankful developers like you are out there willing to help. Was literally working from 22:00 -> 07:00 next day trying to figure this out. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN call_log.from_number = '2228881111' THEN call_log.to_number ELSE call_log.from_number END AS call_counterparty
  , contacts.name
  , SUM(IF(call_log.to_number = '2228881111',1,0)) AS in_call
  , SUM(IF(call_log.from_number = '2228881111',1,0)) AS out_call
FROM `project.dataset.call_log_table` AS call_log
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.contact_list_table` AS contacts
ON contacts.number = CASE WHEN call_log.from_number = '2228881111' THEN call_log.to_number ELSE call_log.from_number END
WHERE '2228881111' IN (call_log.from_number, call_log.to_number)
GROUP BY call_counterparty, contacts.name
```